# how to apply required field validation in ng-repeater

Tags: angularjs

I have a repeater in my application and I am trying to add required field validation on the fields inside repeater. I used $index to generate id/name of the fields.

Form name is IPForm and used inside ng-class to highlight the error. Please see below code snap,

```
<tr ng-repeat="ClaimData in ClaimInfo">
<td>
    <div ng-class="{ 'has-error' : IPForm.DateOfLoss{{$index}}.$invalid }">
        <input type="text" id ="DateOfLoss{{$index}}" name="DateOfLoss{{$index}}" class="datefield form-control" ng-model="DateOfLoss"
            required />
        <span ng-if="IPForm.DateOfLoss{{$index}}.$invalid" class="help-block">Please enter Date of
            Loss.</span>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
```

Problem is its not working at all. I think it is unable to evaluate IPForm.DateOfLoss{{$index}}.$invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use the `ng-form` directive to handle your form validation which is a cleaner solution.

e.g.

```
<tr ng-repeat="ClaimData in ClaimInfo" ng-form="subForm">
<td>
    <div ng-class="{ 'has-error' : subForm.DateOfLoss.$invalid }">
        <input type="text" id ="DateOfLoss{{$index}}" name="DateOfLoss" class="datefield form-control" ng-model="DateOfLoss"
            required />
        <span ng-if="subForm.DateOfLoss.$invalid" class="help-block">Please enter Date of
            Loss.</span>
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
```